# "Incorrect Directory" while adding resource file in android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to add resource file in android studio by right clicking on res folder but it is showing an error "Incorrect Directory". I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: name of directory or file name???

Comment: directry name i think it is liabrary file name

Answer (score 0):

Same problem occured with me.
This problem occurs because of same directory already present in the 'res' folder.
All you have to do is to navigate to 'res' folder in file explorer and you will see a folder created by you earlier OR a folder other than these folders:- 'drawable' ,'minmap' ,'layout' ,'values'. Delete other folders keeping these four folders untouched and try to create resource layout file again !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem occurred with me. This problem occurs because of same directory already present in the **res** folder. All you have to do is to navigate to **res** folder in file explorer and you will see a folder created by you earlier OR a folder other than these folders:- **drawable**, **minmap**, **layout**, **values**. Delete other folders keeping these four folders untouched and try to create resource layout file again.